# Correctness Proof of Simple Accept-Reject Variant

Tags: statistics, random-variables, monte-carlo, simulation

**Problem.** Given
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{f_1(x) - \epsilon f_2(x)}{1 - \epsilon}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and $f_1, f_2$ are two pdfs such that $f_1(x) \geq \epsilon f_2(x)$, prove that the following algorithm generates random variables $X \sim f$:

1. Generate $Y \sim f_1$ and $U \sim Uniform[0, 1]$
2. If $U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y)$ accept $X := Y$; otherwise go to 1.

**Proof.**

$P(X \leq x) = P(Y \leq x \,|\, U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y)) = 
\frac{P(Y \leq x,\, U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y))}{P(U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y))}$.

For the denominator, I get (the integrals go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$)

\begin{align}
P(U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y))
&= \int f_1(y) P(U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y) \,|\, Y = y)dy \\
&= \int f_1(y) P(U \geq \epsilon f_2(y) / f_1(y))dy \\
&= \int f_1(y) (1 - \epsilon f_2(y) / f_1(y))dy \\
&= \int (f_1(y)  - \epsilon f_2(y))dy \\
&= (1- \epsilon)\int f(y)dy \\
&= (1- \epsilon).
\end{align}

Similarly, for the enumerator:

\begin{align}
P(Y \leq x,\, U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y))
&= \int_{-\infty}^x f_1(y) P(Y \leq x, \, U \geq \epsilon f_2(Y) / f_1(Y) \,|\, Y = y)dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x f_1(y) P(U \geq \epsilon f_2(y) / f_1(y))dy \\
&= (1-\epsilon)\int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy.
\end{align}

Combining both, we get

\begin{align}
P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy.
\end{align}

**Trouble**.

However, according to an exercise in a textbook about Monte Carlo, the solution should be
\begin{equation}
P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i.
\end{equation}
Where is the mistake in my solution? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Actually, $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i > 1$, so the textbook's answer must be wrong. But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Your computation is correct, of course: you simulate $f$, as expected. I have no idea what does the textbook mean.